# How many ways are there to break up the regular 9-gon into triangles by diagonals?

Tags: triangles

> How many ways are there to break up the regular 9-gon into triangles by diagonals?

**UPD**
Guaranteed to be convex - yes.
Intersecting "diagonals" be allowed - yes.

**2nd UPD**
It is task for programming course, so there is no need deep math.
It is more about combinatorics.

Comment: Is the nonagon regular?

Comment: @wythagoras Yes it is.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing: are intersections of these diagonals allowed? (Edited:) Otherwise you'll probably have to do something using Catalan numbers.

Comment: Are the vertices of the 9-gon distinguishable? That is, if I break the 9-gon up by adding all edges from vertex 1, is that different from breaking it up by adding all edges from vertex 2?

Comment: @Joffan i didn't cut any words from question. There are not any additional comments. Bad for me - but idk.

Comment: @hardmath does the square of figure make sense? I updated some info.

Comment: I'm more confused than before. @Aero can you tell us what the answer is for a square (4-gon)? Or, if you can manage it, a pentagon (5-gon)?

Comment: I just meant that if you ask about a square (convex quadrilateral) rather than a nonagon, it will be clear that if intersecting diagonals are allowed, this introduces additional triangulations of the figure.  If no intersections, then a square would be triangulated by adding one (of two possible) diagonals, while adding both diagonals would give you another solution (but they would intersect).

Comment: @Joffan For square - answer is 2 I guess.

Comment: @hardmath For square - answer is 2 I guess.

Comment: Okay, that means the diagonals are not allowed to intersect?

Comment: @aero look at the top figure on [this page(link)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html) - does this look like what you are talking about?

Comment: That sounds like intersections are not allowed. And a lot like what I meant to say about Catalan numbers.

Comment: @Joffan add your link as answer pls. It is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways of subdividing a regular polygon into triangles is a well-known property of [Catalan numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html). For a $(n+2)$-sided polygon, there are $C_n$ possible subdivisions.